# Compact metrizable space is separable proof question.

Tags: general-topology

Prove that a compact metrizable space is separable.  I am confused by a specific case of a compact metrizable space.

Let $[0,1]$ be a compact metrizable space.  Since $[0,1]$ is metrizable, it's Hausdorff. Since $[0,1]$ is compact, $[0,1] \subseteq \bigcup_{x_i \in [0,1]} U_{x_i}$ where each $U_{x_i} \cap U_{x_j} = \emptyset$.  Then $[0,1] \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{N} U_{x_{i_{n}}}$.  But this doesn't make sense because there is no finite collection of pairwise disjoint open sets that covers $[0,1]$.  Could someone explain what I'm misunderstanding here?

Comment: I'm confused by your bizarre statement "Since $[0,1]$ is compact, $[0,1] \subseteq \bigcup_{x_i \in [0,1]} U_{x_i}$ where each $U_{x_i} \cap U_{x_j} = \emptyset$." Where did you get that from???

Comment: Of course there is a "finite collection of pairwise disjoint open sets that covers $[0,1].$" The collection I have in mind consists of just one set. But what does that have to do with compactness???

Comment: What part is confusing you?  Since $[0,1]$ is compact, there exists an open cover that has a finite subcover.  Let $U_{x_i}$ be an open set that contains $x_i$.  Since $[0,1]$ is a subset of $R$, a metrizable space, $[0,1]$ is metrizable.  And because of the fact that if a space is metrizable implies that it is a Hausdorff space, $[0,1]$ is a Hausdorff space.  Therefore for each $x_i$ and $x_j$ in $[0,1]$, there exists disjoint open sets that contain $x_i \land x_j$ respectively.  The cover is the union of all the open sets that contain each element respectively and are disjoint.

Comment: "$X$ is compact" does not mean "there exists an open cover . . ."; it means that "***every*** open cover has a finite subcover. And "pairwise disjoint sets" do not enter into the definition of compactness at any point.

Comment: I guess you are thinking something like this: For each pair $(x,y)$ such that $x,y\in[0,1]$ and $x\ne y,$ since $[0,1]$ is Hausdorff, we can choose open sets $U_{x,y}$ and $V_{x,y}$ such that $x\in U_{x,y},\ y\in V_{x,y},$ and $U_{x,y}\cap V_{x,y}=\emptyset.$ Let $\mathcal W=\mathcal U\cup\mathcal V,$ where $\mathcal U$ is the collection of all the $U_{x,y}$ and $\mathcal V$ is the collection of all the $V_{x,y}.$ Then $\mathcal W$ is an open cover of $[0,1]$ and by compactness it has a finite subcover. And for some reason you think that finite subcover is pairwise disjoint. Is that it?

Comment: Of course $\mathcal W$ covers $[0,1];$ in fact each of the subfamilies $\mathcal U$ and $\mathcal V$ already covers $[0,1].$ But $\mathcal W,$ though it contains a lot of disjoint pairs, is not pairwise disjoint; "pairwise disjoint" would mean that ***every*** pair of sets in $\mathcal W$ is disjoint. And there's no reason for the finite subcover to be pairwise disjoint. In fact it can't possibly be pairwise disjoint, unless it consists of just one set (which it doesn't), because $[0,1]$ is connected.

Comment: This is what I'm thinking:  Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be any two elements of $[0,1]$.  Since $[0,1]$ is Hausdorff, $x_1 \in U_{x_1} \land x_2 \in U_{x_2} \land U_{x_1} \cap U_{x_2} = \emptyset$.  Let the open cover for $[0,1]$ be $\bigcup_{x_i \in [0,1]} U_{x_i}$ such that each $U_{x_i} \cap U_{x_j} = \emptyset$.  Then there exists a finite subcover.

Comment: "Hausdorff" means that, ***given two distinct points*** $x$ and $y,$ you can find disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ (depending on both $x$ and $y$) such that $x\in U$ and $y\in V$ and $U\cap V=\emptyset.$ Hausdorff does ***NOT*** mean that you can find open sets $U_x$ depending only on $x$ such that $U_{x_1}\cap U_{x_2}=\emptyset$ whenever $x_1\ne x_2.$ That would mean that $U_x=\{x\}$ for every $x,$ which means you have the so-called discrete topology.

Answer (score 3):

The def'n of compactness is not based on pair-wise disjoint open families. A space $S$ is compact iff whenever $F$ is a family of open subsets of $S$ with $\cup F=S,$ there is a finite $G\subset F$ with $\cup G=S.$  It does not matter whether the members of  $F$ or $G$ are pair-wise disjoint or not. (....And if the space $S$ is connected, and $F$ is a cover of $S$ by pair-wise disjoint open sets, then the only possible members of $F$ are $\emptyset$ and $S.$)

Let $S$ be a compact metrizable space and let $d$ be a metric for $S.$ For each $n\in N$ the family $F_n=\{B_d(x,1/n): x\in S\}$ is an open cover of $S.$

For each $n\in N $ let $G_n=\{B_d(x,1/n):x\in C_n\}$ be a subcover of $F_n$ (i.e. $G_n\subset F_n$ and $\cup G_n=S$), where $C_n$ is a finite subset of $S.$ It follows that the countable set $T=\cup_{n\in N}C_n$ is dense in $S.$

To prove this, it suffices to show that $T\cap B_d(y,r)\ne \emptyset$ whenever $y\in S$ and $r>0.$ Consider that every $G_n$  is a cover of $S,$ so  take any $n\in N$ with $1/n<r.$  There exists $\sigma\in C_n$ such that $y\in B_d(\sigma,1/n).$ Then $d(y,\sigma)<1/n<r$ so $\sigma \in B_d(y,r).$ Hence $\sigma \in T\cap B_d(y,r).$

Comment: What exactly is $C_n$?  Is it the set of all $x$ whose open balls of radius $1 \backslash n$ covers $S$?

Comment: Each  $G_n$  is a finite cover of $S$ by open balls of radius $1/n, $  and $C_n$ is a finite set of centers of the members of $G_n.$